# Using UINavigationController with UIViewControllers having transparent background

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Default behaviour of `UINavigationController` is slowly moving *currentViewController* to the left and the newly pushed viewcontroller to over that a little faster.

This works beautifully with solid background.

I need to use transparent background for all viewcontrollers inside that `UINavigationController` stack. In this case, the default behaviour causes viewcontrollers to overlap each other (as expected, as they have no background, they will look like they are mixed together) until push/pop of viewcontrollers are completed. This looks ugly.

Is there anything that can be done with default or subclassed `UINavigationController`?

Comment: if you want transparent background then you can use alpha property

Comment: @Anonymous I already do transparency. The transition is ugly with transparency. That is why I am trying to figure out altering that transition.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a custom push/pop transition as described [here](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html). You could do a simple slide transition where the view controllers do not overlap, making your push animation look fine.

Comment: I need to support iOS 6.0+ :-/